# How to get rid of getting alert "This type of files may harm your computer. Do you want to keep or discard?"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to download files from website using selenium and chrome webdriver in python and i am getting the alert to keep or discard. I have tried every way as mentioned on stackoverflow to change the chrome option and preferences, but of no use.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have exact URL to the file you can use `urlretrieve("URL","File Name")` from `from urllib.request`.

Comment: I cannot make use of url path, since it is default for my webpage, only content of page is getting changed. @TekNath

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  prefs = {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false'}
  chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Comment: Yes...I have tried these things                                                    
    preferences = {"download.default_directory": download_dir,
                       "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                       "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                       "download.extensions_to_open": 'inf',
                         "download.extensions_to_open": 'cfg',
                   "safebrowsing.enabled": True,                       
               "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1}  @Amruta